# Item level permission column dependend

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions

I am struggling with setting up the SharePoint list permission on the item level.

I need to allow the user to view and edit the item ***only if*** their name is in one of three custom columns or they created the item.

Basically, the whole exercise can be done by adding a column that would check whether the username is in any of four columns (creator + 3 custom ones) and setting up permission on that one column.

Can anyone advise it's feasible to do?

Unfortunately, I am limited only to SharePoint designer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your requirement I can suggest you below two solutions:

**Solution 1**:

Create a new list view and add filter of `[Me]` on these 4 columns (by using `OR`). this way user can see only those items in which he has been added to either of these columns. (This is a kind of workaround. so you need make sure user cannot create/see another list views like all items).

**Solution 2**:

You can create and run workflow/Microsoft flow(if available) on new item creation and grant the permission on list item to only user who has been added to either of these 4 fields (and maybe grant permission to site/list owner as well for safer side).

Comment: Hi @Michal, does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others in future to find the correct answer easily.